# What is the safest way to encrypt a password that can be decrypted at a later time?

Tags: encryption, passwords, web-application, decryption

In a web app I'm building, I need to use Apple's AutoIngestion tool for iTunes Connect. In this tool it seems the only way to use it is to send a password in plain text.

What would be the best approach for saving a user's iTunes Connect password and then retrieving it at a later time? I do understand that two-way encryption is bad for passwords but there doesn't seem to be an alternate way for this.

Comment: It would be nice to have a little more context as to the details of your problem. I am just going by the assumption that you are building a hosted web application, thereby implying you are managing the user's credentials for them on your system. Also, we don't know about the actual flow of your program at the moment you need to access these credentials, are you within the context of a user interaction (web request), or an asynchronous/scheduled background process which fetches the data?

Comment: The application will work by getting a user to enter their credentials for iTunes Connect and then my server will periodically connect to iTunes Connect to update the statistics to present to the user whenever they log in to the app.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, what seems like the best way to handle this is to use the functionality provided by your OS to store credentials and password.

On OSX and iOS, you can use keychain. Under Windows, you can use the credential manager (also called password vault), DPAPI or the certificate store, depending on what exactly you want to do. In any case, I suggest you head to Stackoverflow and ask implementation specific systems.